# Implementing a animated form in lwuit

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form

I read this article :

http://lwuit.blogspot.in/2008/06/lightweight-text-input-in-lwuit.html

This article talks of autocomplete textfield embedded on a form which has a background image which is animated. As in there is a fish which is swimming and ifeel it looks really cool.

How is that implemented? Where should I start? I wish to do the same with my form: an animation in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very easy using the LWUIT Resource Editor. You should create a TimeLine Image (using a the Tab images) and add it to the background of your application. You can use the add animated Gif option which converts an animated GIF to a timeline.

Comment: So basically, I open my existing theme with resource editor and then look around for creating tab images..alright. how do i add it to the background? Can you supply a small code snippet?

Comment: Sorry. What I want to mean is the next. Open the Resource Editor. Create a theme. Ok, in the bar options, there is a Image tab (not for the theme, there are option tabs up) and there, use Option "images" to add an image and convert to MultiImage. The last step is, go to the themes tab and open the propierties from the Form. Use the image as a background. Tell me if you need more help.

Comment: Fixed the answer from multi-image to timeline animation/gif.